# How to choose the i-th file when using Directory.EnumerateFiles Method

Tags: c#, for-loop

How can we specify the i-th file when using EnumerateFiles method?

The code below is using `foreach` to loop through the files:

```cs
var txtFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(sourceDirectory, "*.txt");

foreach (string currentFile in txtFiles)
{
    string fileName = currentFile.Substring(sourceDirectory.Length + 1);
    Directory.Move(currentFile, Path.Combine(archiveDirectory, fileName));
}
```

What if I just want the 2nd file? `txtFiles[1]` does not seem to work.

Comment: I don't think `EnumerateFiles` makes any guarantees with respect to the order in which results are returned, so I'd be sceptical of any method that relies on "the 2nd file" to work correctly.

Comment: `string secondFile = Directory.EnumerateFiles(sourceDirectory, "*.txt").ElementAtOrDefault(1));` to get either 2nd file or `null` (if 2nd file doesn't exist). Note, that since you don't put `OrderBy` there's no guarantee which file will be returned

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `ElementAt` extension method from LINQ:

```cs
var txtFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(sourceDirectory, "*.txt");
var secondFile = txtFiles.ElementAt(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Please, note, that since you *don't specify* order, e.g. `OrderBy` there is *no guarantee* what second file
will be returned from, say, `a.txt`, `b.txt`, `c.txt`. Technically, you can put

```
 // Either some second file or null (if we have 1 or less files)
 string secondFile = Directory
   .EnumerateFiles(sourceDirectory, "*.txt")
   .ElementAtOrDefault(1);
```

It seems that you want to archive *some* files (which match some pattern); you can add `Where` to *filter out* such files:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

...

//TODO: Put the right pattern here
string pattern = "^[AaBb]";

var filesToArchive = Directory
  .EnumerateFiles(sourceDirectory, "*.txt")
  .Where(file => Regex.IsMatch(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtensions(file), pattern));

foreach (string file in filesToArchive) 
  try {
    Directory.Move(file, 
                   Path.Combine(archiveDirectory, Path.GetFileName(file)), 
                   true);   
  }
  catch (IOException) {
    //TODO: file can be removed, locked etc. in the process 
  }
```